# Linking webserver directory from one OS to another OS

Tags: linux, windows, nginx, webserver

I have dual OS on my laptop installed (Ubuntu and Windows 10).

I want to keep two webservers synchronized, is it possible to make Nginx in Ubuntu to use the web directory in Windows (lets say P1) instead?

I'd tried to change the directory to P1, what I've got is an 500 Internal Error, but it works fine if I change it back to the default `/var/www/html` (already chmoded permissions to P1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you do not think as "Use linux directories in windows?". Try to install something like http://www.paragon-drivers.com/extfs-windows/ and use linux directories from windows

Comment: Oops forgot to think it reversely, thanks! will try it later :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount your windows partition on Ubuntu and set that directory to your document root.